# PDF Generation having multi-lingual text using Flying Saucer

Tags: java, pdf, flying-saucer

I am trying to print Arabic and English text in PDF using Flying Saucer library. Here's my code :

```
    String inputFile = "D:/test.xhtml";
    String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();
    String outputFile = "D:/doc.pdf";
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    ITextFontResolver resolver = renderer.getFontResolver();
    resolver.addFont("D:/arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

    renderer.setDocument(url);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os);

    os.close();
```

and my XHTML file has following data enclosed in paragraph tags: 
اب اب اب اب Hello

The output generated displays only English characters but not Arabic glyphs. Please help.

Comment: Add the language tag. Is it java?

Comment: Yeah. Java code converting XHTML to PDF using this library.

Comment: Are you setting the font of the document to your `arialuni` font? You need to actually change the font of the text in the document.

Answer (score 0):

> for some reason, if no specific font is used, the generated PDF uses some kind of  default (probably Helvetica) font, that contains a very limited character set, that obviously does not contain the Greek code page.
>   [Reference](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2015/02/15/unicode-characters-dropped-in-pdf-files-generated-with-itext-and-flying-saucer/)

Arial is a pretty standard font, installed by default in most operating system, and implements a wide variety of alphabets (including Greek).